# Pisma Unique constraint failed

Tags: constraints, schema, unique, prisma

Hello (i'm french sorry for my bad english!!)

i want to create database for a project with prisma schema, with a table of users, an other for the comments that users written, and a finally for the likes (each user can like each comment).

so my schema is :

```js
model User {
  idUser     Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  pseudo     String    @unique @db.VarChar(100)
  password   String    @db.VarChar(255)
  role       Role      @default(USER)
  nom        String    @db.VarChar(100)
  prenom     String    @db.VarChar(100)
  email      String    @unique @db.VarChar(100)
  info_email String    @default("null") @db.VarChar(200)

  writtenComments Comment[]
  likes Like [] 

  @@unique([idUser, pseudo])
}

model Comment {
  idComment         Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title      String  @db.VarChar(100)
  comment      String  @db.VarChar(200)

  author     User    @relation(fields: [authorId, authorPseudo], references: [idUser, pseudo], onDelete: Cascade)
  authorId   Int
  authorPseudo String

  likes Like [] 

  @@unique([idComment, title, authorPseudo, authorId])
}

model Like {
  idLikes         Int     @id @default(autoincrement())

  Liker     User    @relation( fields: [LikerId, LikerPseudo], references: [idUser, pseudo], onDelete: Cascade)
  LikerId   Int
  LikerPseudo String

  Commented     Comment    @relation(fields: [commentId, commentTitle, commentAuthor, commentAuthorId ], references: [idComment, title, authorPseudo,authorId], onDelete: Cascade)
  commentId   Int
  commentTitle String
  commentAuthor String
  commentAuthorId Int

  @@unique([commentId, LikerId])
}

enum Role {
  USER
  ADMIN
}
```

the problem :
on like is the combination of one comment and one user, but the unique constraint failed. And in my database i can have two id like for a comment liked by the same user !! So one user can like any times he want a same comment. And when i add the unique constraint in the Like table, a message of failed appeared. :/

```
Error: P2002

Unique constraint failed on the constraint: `Like_commentId_LikerId_key
```

thank for your help i hope your suggestion can help me =)

have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

sorry

the problem was that my table wasn't purged before I pushed my schema. The constraint is ok =)